# When to use a terminal pin?

Tags: soldering, mechanical, reliability

[image]

Would you ever be advised to solder hookup wire to a terminal pin (and maybe sleeve it with heat shrink) instead of soldering it directly to the PCB?

Comment: I do this all the time when I want a firm connection, but also know that I might have to change it often. Soldering on the terminal pin is more robust that on the PCB since PCB might get damaged by repeated solder/ desolder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, wire-to-board connections are often made with a variety of terminal pins in order to increase their mechanical strength, current carrying capability and optimise form factor.

The most common terminals used are turrets and solder cups. Turrets allow a wire to be hooked around it at a right angle to the terminal. Solder cups allow wire mounting to be vertical. Both have their place in designs.

There is a solder specification for these types of connections, IPC-A-610. There are images of these terminals in the document, which I will not link to but can be found on google.